# TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type bool that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, masking

I am trying to send two inputs to my LSTM layer. One is the input vector and another one is the input mask. The mask vector is boolean, and the input vector is float.

```
#Input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(17640,1),name='input_layer')

#Input layer
input_mask = Input(shape=(17640,),name='input_mask')

#LSTM layer
lstm = LSTM(25,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),return_sequences=True, 
            name='lstm')(inputs=input_layer, mask=input_mask)

#Dense layer
dense = Dense(units=50,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(seed=3), 
              kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), name='dense')(layer)

#output layer
output = Dense(units=10,activation='softmax', name='output')(dense)

#Creating a model
model = Model(inputs=[input_layer, input_mask],outputs=output)
```

But I am getting this error. I think the mask vector is supposed to be boolean.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype bool: <tf.Tensor 'SequenceMask/Less:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=bool>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type bool that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.
```

Here is the full traceback of the error which I am facing

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    469               as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 470               preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    471         except TypeError as err:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1443           "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
-> 1444           (dtype.name, value.dtype.name, value))
   1445     return value

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype bool: <tf.Tensor 'SequenceMask/Less:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=bool>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-f2b802415d9a> in <module>
     12 #LSTM layer
     13 lstm = LSTM(25,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),return_sequences=True, 
---> 14             name='lstm')(inputs=input_layer, mask=input_mask)
     15 
     16 #layer = MyLayer()(inputs=input_layer, mask=input_mask)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    653 
    654     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 655       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    656 
    657     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    925                     not base_layer_utils.is_in_eager_or_tf_function()):
    926                   with auto_control_deps.AutomaticControlDependencies() as acd:
--> 927                     outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
```

Please provide some suggestions to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
input_mask = Input(shape=(17640,),name='input_mask',dtype="bool")
```